# CSS Vertical-Align Bottom Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make below layout with HTML & CSS

```
|-----------------------------------------|
|box 1                                    |
|               -----------               |
|               | box 3   |               |
|---------------|         |---------------|
|---------------|         |---------------|
|box 2          |         |               |
|               |         |               |
|               |         |               |
|---------------|---------|---------------|
```

With (something like) below code,

```
<div class="box-one"></div>
<div class="box-two">
    <div class="box-three"></div>
</div>

.box-one {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:50px;
    width: 400px;
}
.box-two {
    border: 1px solid green;
    height:100px;
    text-align : center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 400px;
}
.box-three {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:120px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nalaka526/4a4aD/1/)

But it seems `box-two`,  `text-align : center;` & `vertical-align: bottom;` is not applied, so the output is not as expected. Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: `vertical-align` only has an effect on elements who's display is `table-cell`.

Comment: @antony : No, it just has a different effect on inline-block elements. One of the problems here is that he needs to set box-three's `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @Sort of a beginner You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/4a4aD/10/

DIV's `display: block` by default. To use the `vertical-align` css property then you need to start using properties like `display: table-cell` or `display: inline-block`. Also the `text-align` won't affect block elements so that property you added has no effect.

But it looks as though your doing something different there. You've got `box-3` overlapping `box-1`. So either you need to give it a negative `margin-top` or start using absolute positioning like this:

```
.box-one {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:50px;
    width: 400px;
}
.box-two {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height:100px;
    width: 400px;
}
.box-three {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 175px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:120px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.box-three {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:120px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: -21px auto 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4a4aD/7/

Or alternatively, a bit more generic:

```
.box-two {
    /* ... */

    position: relative;
}

.box-three {
    /* ... */

    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4a4aD/9/

Answer (score 0):

to center a div you just need to use `margin: auto;`.
So it would look something like this: 
`.box-three {
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:120px;
    width: 50px;
}`